# Using Asp.NET Identity with custom user manager/database

Tags: asp.net, identity

I would like to use some parts of the Identity system of Asp.NET to access a custom database, but not all of the parts.
The database portion wasn't too difficult, but I am trying to find out how to write code to put to work some of the Identity methods into my custom implementation. For example one of the differing items is to not use the UserManager password hash, but instead use some other 3rd party password hash function. Some of the things I'd like to take advantage of is the cookie authentication, password validator fields, etc.
So, first thing I tried to do is look at what the standard CreateAsync method does, and it takes me to a blank line looking something like this:

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(UserManager<>.<CreateAsync>d__73))]
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password);
```

How can I make custom create-async and password-verification functions?
Oh, also by 'custom database' I mean, I do not want to use the tables that come with Identity, no Roles, Claims, just my own Users table is all.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this but there's too much code to post it all here as an answer unfortunately.

For CreateAsync you need to make a custom userstore class that implements `IUserStore<your custom user>, IUserPasswordStore<your custom user>` 
    then you need to implement the CreateAsync method:

```
async Task<IdentityResult> IUserStore<your custom user>.CreateAsync(your custom user user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            IdentityResult result;
            var tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => result = someDataAccessClass.SomeSaveUserToDatabaseFUnction(user));

            return await tsk;
        }
```

You can implement the data class and save user function however you want at that point.

The password verification is a little more complex depending on what you do.

You'll have to create a custom `SignInManager` that inherits from the the regular SignInManager. Then just override the `PasswordSignInAsync` method with whatever you're doing security-wise. Also note that you'll need to implement some of the other functions on the UserManager like find user async and stuff like that.

Also note that for the Identity Pipeline to fill in the missing pieces you need to do `services.AddIdentity().AddUserStore().AddSignInManger` (and all the other classes you customize) in your startup.cs configureservices() method and then throw `app.UseIDentity()` into your configure method too.

Comment: Okay this is a lot of understand, I think I'll spend some time on it. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: yeah it took awhile to figure out how to do it since MS insists on stuffing Entity Framework into it. If you want to try a different path, I found this page AFTER finally getting the identity to work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

Comment: Alright, so the magic is further inside "SomeSaveUserToDatabaseFUnction" .. am I correct in guessing that inside it you simply add some properties to a record that you add to the db context and do the SaveChanges() on it?

Comment: yeah so if you're saving to the database that's where you'd open a connection, create a command object and assign the parameters. Normally Identity would want to write to its own tables but since you want to write to a custom user table or whatever you have to do the custom code in there. If you're using EF just do whatever you normally do when you save data using that.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to mess with the () => result = ... function and it tells me that my type of my CustomUser cannot be implicitly converted to the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityResult . I am used to using the EF and was thinking my adding line would be like this:
`() => result = database.MyDataBaseTable.Add(user)`

Comment: I hate EF so I haven't used it in several years so I can't help you with that. In my example that SomeSaveUserToDatabase function basically just maps the properties of the user object to sql params. If you're using EF, just replace the call to the function with whatever logic adds it to the database with EF.

Comment: Oh, sorry - yea nevermind, I think I am really close to making this work now.

Comment: I have found a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbSqi3Amatw#t=5.839208) which shows making the system work with custom database, but it still relies on having tables made for all the Asp data tables for the claims, etc. 
Then, I found this page (https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/) which let me forget about the extra tables, etc and just use the cookie authentication, thanks to a search sparked by your link above.